# aspnet_compiler incremental precompile

Tags: asp.net, precompile, aspnet-compiler

I have a website project and I want to make aspnet_compiler precompile incrementally  (right now it cleans out everything and recompile everything from scratch)

I tried to delete the -f flag, and use fixednames, but then it gave me this error error ASPRUNTIME: The target directory is not empty.

am I suppose to delete the target directory after each instance of precompiling?